# SwiftUI: NavigationStack appends all items of list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a `NavigationStack` in SwiftUI and an `ObservedObject` and enum that handle the routing.

```swift
enum Route {
  case location(location: Location)
}

extension Route: Hashable {
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.hashValue)
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.location(let lhsLocation), .location(let rhsLocation)):
      return lhsLocation.uid == rhsLocation.uid
    default:
      return true
    }
  }
}

extension Route {
  @ViewBuilder
  func view(vm: LocationViewModel, router: NavigationRouter) -> some View {
    switch self {
    case .location(let location):
      LocationView(location: location)
        .environmentObject(vm)
        .environmentObject(router)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
final class NavigationRouter: ObservableObject {
  
  @Published var routes = [Route]()
  
  @Published var didPressBack = false
  
  func push (to screen: Route) {
    guard !routes.contains(screen) else {
      return
    }
    routes.append(screen)
  }
  
  func reset() {
    routes = []
  }
  
  func removeLast() {
    print("Route count \(routes.count)")
    _ = routes.popLast()
  }
}
```

```swift
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $navigationRouter.routes) {
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
          List {
              LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(locations, id: \.uid) { location in
                NavigationLink(value: Route.location(location: location)) {
                  DummyListItem()
                 }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
      }
    }
      .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) {
        $0.view(vm: vm, router: navigationRouter)
      }
  }
```

I have three items in the `List` and when I tap on a `DummyListItem()`, all items in the list get added to the stack. Previously, I had them in a `ScrollView` instead of a `List` and only one item got appended, but now that I'm using `List` they all are.

Any suggestions for why this change may be causing this?

Comment: Please provide all the missing code to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to have multiple navigationDestination per type of value and a NavigationPath to store the values. No need for routes or view models.